# Mirroring Process's console output to UI in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, 7zip

I have an app that, as part of its workflow, extracts zipped archives using 7zip.exe. In order to capture the output (see what got extracted and/or if there were errors), I use

```
pro.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pro.RedirectStandardError = true;
pro.UseShellExecute = false;
```

when launching the 7zip application. However, this prevents 7zip from showing its output to its own console, which both leads to an unsatisfying long empty console window when extracting large archives, and also prevents the user from seeing potential errors or causes of a hang.

I'd really like to have my app capture the output and immediately mirror it to a new window or a UserControl within the main window to keep the user updated during extraction. However, I'm having a lot of trouble finding the correct async architecture for this; everything I try either mirrors correctly but doesn't await the result, leading to downstream errors caused by execution before extraction finishes, or awaits execution but doesn't mirror until the action is complete, such as in this example: https://i.imgur.com/QDJUkDX.gif

Relevant code snippets are below, but here are the full contexts:

View model that calls the 7zip extractor: https://github.com/Synthesis-Collective/SynthEBD/blob/7ZipOutputRedirect/SynthEBD/GUI_Aux/ViewModels/VM_ConfigDrafter.cs

7zip extractor: https://github.com/Synthesis-Collective/SynthEBD/blob/7ZipOutputRedirect/SynthEBD/General_Aux/7ZipInterface.cs

Snippets with irrelevant text excluded:

Constructor for the view model that calls the 7zip extractor should wait for ExtractArchivesAsync to finish and then operate on the extracted contents.

```
public VM_ConfigDrafter()
{
    DraftConfigButton = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(
        execute: async _ =>
        {
            IsInstalling = true;
            var destinationDirs = await ExtractArchivesAsync();
            _configDrafter.DraftConfigFromTextures(CurrentConfig, destinationDirs, true, unmatchedTextures);
        });
```

ExtractArchivesAsync should go through each selected path and extract it using the 7Zip extractor;

```
public async Task<List<string>> ExtractArchivesAsync()
{
    List<string> destinationDirs = new();
    var destinationDir = "";
    foreach (var archiveFile in SelectedFileArchives)
    {
        // get destination dir here
        _7ZipInterface().ExtractAndRedirectAsync(archiveFile.FilePath, destinationDir);
    }
    return destinationDirs;
}
```

Constructor for the 7zip extractor:

```
public class _7ZipInterface : VM
{
    private readonly IEnvironmentStateProvider _environmentStateProvider;
    private string _sevenZipPath => Path.Combine(_environmentStateProvider.InternalDataPath, "7Zip",
                        Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86", "7z.exe");

    public delegate _7ZipInterface Factory();
    public _7ZipInterface(IEnvironmentStateProvider environmentStateProvider)
    {
        _environmentStateProvider = environmentStateProvider;

        RedirectedOutputLines.ToObservableChangeSet().Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).Subscribe(x => RedirectedOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, RedirectedOutputLines)).DisposeWith(this);
    }

    public string RedirectedOutput { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> RedirectedOutputLines { get; set; } = new();
```

Extractor's function to launch a "redirection output" window for mirroring 7zip output and run the actual extraction function (eventually I'll change it to async Task so the calling function can have access to the output, but solving one problem at a time for now):

```
public async void ExtractAndRedirectAsync(string archivePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        RedirectedOutputLines.Clear();
        var window = new Window_7ZipInterface();
        window.DataContext = this;
        window.Show();
#pragma warning disable CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
            ExtractArchiveAsync(archivePath, destinationPath, RedirectedOutputLines);
#pragma warning restore CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
            //window.Close();
        }
```

Finally, the extraction function itself:

```
public async Task<bool> ExtractArchiveAsync(string archivePath, string destinationPath, ObservableCollection<string> redirectedOutputs)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pro.FileName = _sevenZipPath;
        pro.Arguments = string.Format("x \"{0}\" -y -o\"{1}\"", archivePath, destinationPath);
        try
        {
            pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pro.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pro.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pro.UseShellExecute = false;

            string redirectedOutput = "";
            using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = pro, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
            {
                process.Start();

                // Capture the standard output
                StringBuilder standardOutputCapture = new StringBuilder();

                // Asynchronously read the standard output
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Data != null)
                    {
                        redirectedOutputs.Add(e.Data);
                        standardOutputCapture.AppendLine(e.Data); // Capture in buffer
                    }
                };

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                // Wait for the process to exit
                process.WaitForExit();

                // Do something with the captured standard output
                redirectedOutput = standardOutputCapture.ToString();
                if (redirectedOutput.Contains("Can't open as archive"))
                {
                    CustomMessageBox.DisplayNotificationOK("File Extraction Error", "Extraction of " + archivePath + " appears to have failed with message: " + Environment.NewLine + redirectedOutput.Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CustomMessageBox.DisplayNotificationOK("File Extraction Error", "Extraction of " + archivePath + " failed with message: " + Environment.NewLine + ExceptionLogger.GetExceptionStack(e));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The way all this is supposed to come together is that ExtractArchiveAsync() gets a new redirected output line from 7Zip and adds it to redirectedOutputs. The 7zip extractor view model is subscribed to redirectedOutputs, so when that collection changes it gets appended to string RedirectedOutputLines, which is what's displayed in Window_7ZipInterface.

In practice what happens is the above - either I await the execution of ExtractArchivesAsync() in which case the entire extraction finishes before the output gets displayed in Window_7ZipInterface, or I don't await and the downstream functions get called on erroneous inputs because extraction hasn't finished yet.

Is there a workaround for this that won't pause the UI thread but will prevent downstream tasks from running until ExtractArchivesAsync() has finished executing?